# Rank Test for a Matrix

Tags: statistical-significance, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix A corrupted with noise and I am looking for a test that tests the null hypothesis that the matrix A, rank(A)==1 v.s. rank(A)>1. I checked a little the literature and this paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/3533192?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents
suggests a test. I guess there might be more. Do anyone know a software implementation (any platform of the above test)? Or some other test for this purpose?

Comment: Would matrix condition number help you?

Comment: @Aksakal I'm having a hard time seeing how that alone would help.  In order to make progress, one needs to estimate the magnitude of the noise relative to the magnitudes of the coefficients.  For intuition, consider a matrix with one nonzero value.  The corrupted version easily could have a small condition number, especially if the ratio of its dimensions is large.

Comment: Any test would need information about how the matrix is corrupted by noise.